# Can a hard link refer to a file in a different filesystem?

Tags: filesystem, inode, hard-link

Can a hard link refer to a file in a different filesystem? Why or why not?

Comment: Is there a reason you are posting only tangentially-related-to-Ubuntu exam questions and *only* exam questions as your questions?  Many of these questions can be lifted from any number of exams (and such questions are typically not supposed to be mass-shared like you're doing)

Answer (score 4):

No, it can't.

Files on a linux file system are internally referred to by a unique number, an inode. That inode corresponds to records of where the file is stored on the volume. Two different filenames, possibly in a different path on the same volume, can share the same inode. At that point, one is a hard link to the other, and vice versa.

The inode refers to space on the current volume. Each file in fact is a hard link to an inode on the volume. It is not a matter of one file referring to the other, leave alone referring to another one on a different volume. It is a matter of two file names sharing the same inode.